# Selecting different tones for the local notification in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im developing a medicine app.

Here my client want to select different tones for local notifications and that tones is to be selected from a picker.

Is this possible to set different tones for local notifications.

Can any one please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to "select" different audio tones to your notifications. I think you would need to create your own custom picker though.

Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html) for some general guidelines of the audio (must be less than 30 seconds, proper file format, location to read from, etc)